# Tensorflow - how to predict modular arithmetic/clock arithmetic (angles)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working on a machine learning project where I'm using TensorFlow (and DNNRegressor). I want to predict a modular arithmetic value (an angle) ranging between -pi and pi. When I try doing it "the normal way" the model isn't very good, as it doesn't understand that -pi and pi is actually the same value.

Does tensorflow have any functionality to make ML models with modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should output two values in this case: sin(angle) and cos(angle). Then you can reconstruct the real angle from this (school trigonometry). 
The loss function can be a sum of RMSEs for each output.